# Missing upward arrow and downward arrow material icons

Tags: javascript, angular, icons, angular-material2

I am using material icons, which I love, BTW. So, I've looked at the ligatures here: https://material.io/icons/ and been using them.

But I have a screen where two of the icons aren't showing up and I can't figure it out. Here is my HTML:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onUpClick()">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow upward</i>
        </button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onDownClick()">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow downward</i>
        </button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClearClick()">
          <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onDeleteClick()">
          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </button>
</p>
```

Clear and delete show up, but the upward and downward arrows don't show up. Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hntkry?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I've googled, but can't find issues where some of the icons show up, but not others.

Comment: You need to use arrow_downward and arrow_upward. Check this for more clarification https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_upward

Comment: @LukeP.Issac Your comment was extremely helpful. I had never clicked on one of the icons before and it was helpful to learn to do that and it would show you the ligature to use.

Comment: I was anticipating same so added the url here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrow_upward` and `arrow_downward` are spelled with `_` between the words and not a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked Material+Icons font family? If no, Please do

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

as well as @Mateusz Juruś is right, there should be `_` instead of `space`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>` instead of `<i class="material-icons">arrow downward</i>`

Comment: That's a different icon.